# Profile both OpenACC and CPU code

Tags: profiling, openacc, pgi

I'm experimenting with some OpenACC code targeting a GPU.

In my experiments I run some parts of the code on the GPU and others on the CPU.

```
//Loop that seems to run well on a GPU
#pragma acc parallel loop
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
...

//Loop that, for whatever reason, might run better on a CPU
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
...
```

The problem is inferring the effect this has on performance. Using `PGI_ACC_TIME`, I can get information about how long loops are taking on the GPU, but it's not clear how to interleave this with information about the CPU.

Is there a way to interleave timing information from both the CPU and GPU? Command-line utilities are desirable since most of my sessions are remote, but a method using GUIs is probably okay.

Comment: Have you tried [NVIDIA Visual Profiler](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler)? It profiles the code and shows very useful information...

Comment: You can try `pgprof` as well, it's distributed with PGI compilers and seems to be a shortcut for NVIDIA Visual Profiler... Not sure how they correlate.

Comment: You can use NVPROF (Nvidia) or PGPROF (PGI).  They basically the same profiler with some minor versioning differences.  Also PGPROF, the default is to include CPU profiling while with NVPROF you'll need to enable it using the "--cpu-profiling on" command line option.  When you view the data in the GUI, look for the "CPU" tab to view the CPU times.  Viewing the profile from the command line, the default is a "bottom-up" view which you may change via the "--cpu-profiling-mode" flag to "top-down" or "flat".  I prefer "top-down".